# JAVA: Strategy to design large object which can be persisted into harddisk when its size is too large

Tags: java, memory

We have limited memory and we'd like to have way to persist large object into harddisk when its size is over a defined number (i.e 100M). This object can still be used by other function when it's called.

Any idea to implement such kind of object?

Comment: So ... what kind of object is this? If you are referring to general Java classes (or a spaghetti of them) then what do you expect? Btw an OS with virtual memory system will be able to transparently page out less frequently used blocks of memory. However this will degrade system performance. Read: Thrashing (computer operating systems).

Comment: This is a Session object which contains a lot of information of one user connection. We want to exceed the number of connections but the memory issue blocking it.

Comment: I believe there will be a way to *avoid such HUGE object* in memory definitely. Could you be more specific for your problem?

Comment: we do have another plan to reduce the information in this object, but we still need the solution to persist part of objects in memory into harddisk when it's not active.

Answer (score 0):

-> Use the [java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html) class to get the size of object like this:-

```
instrumentation.getObjectSize(objectInstance);
```

-> check if the size increases beyond 100 M

-> if it does, [Serialize](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaSerialization/article.html) the Object, and save it to a file on harddisk

Comment: Thanks. Serilaize/Deserilize is required here. A strategy to manage these objects is appreciative.

Comment: Welcome, what do you mean by strategy to manage these objects ?

Comment: Yes. When to persist and remove them out of memory and when to call them back.

Comment: Why don't you use a DB ?

Comment: Well you mentioned you need to save object when its size exceeds a predefined limit, you can save it at that time. Removing them out of memory is really GCs job, you can dereference it when you are done. And whenever your program requires your object state, or when it start you can load from the file etc, it really depends on your requirements.

Comment: @SvetlinZarev yes you can use db, I am just giving a suggestion, user is free to explore :)